# change values of dictionary to be a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-files

ok so I have this code that will take in a text file with names, and then make a dictionary with the first letter of each name as the keys and the repetition of this letter as the values. I need to change it to where the values is a list of the names corresponding to that initial letter. I got up to where it counts how many names for every letter there is but I don't know how to then take these names and turn them into a list, to be the values. 
It should do something like this:

(this is he text file my function will read)

```
Mary
Jane
Anna
Judith
Kim
Melody
Myriam
Lauren
Betty
Holley
```

then the dictionary should do this

```
{'A':['Anna'], 'B':['Betty'], 'H':['Holley'], 'J':['Judith','Jane'], 'K': 
['Kim'], 'L':['Lauren'], 'M':['Mary','Melody','Myriam']}
```

but mine will just return this:

```
{'A':1, 'B':1, 'H':1, 'J':2, 'K':1, 'L':1, 'M':3}
```

How do I change it to where I get the names?

Here is my code:

```
def newDictionary():
    names={}
    char = []
    file = open(names)
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        1char = file.read(line[1])
        1char.append(char)
        for keys,values in names():

    return names
```

Comment: You can't start a variable name with a number. You have to write something like `firstChar` not `1char`. Also, string indexes start at 0, not 1, and you don't need to do `file.read(line[0])` because `line[0]` is a string.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to generate the name lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def newDictionary(filename):
    names = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                names[line[0]].append(line)
    return names
```

Example of how to generate dictionary of name lists by first letter:

```
name_lists = newDictionary("names.txt")
print name_lists
```

> defaultdict(, {
>       'A': ['Anna'],
>       'B': ['Betty'],
>       'H': ['Holley'],
>       'K': ['Kim'],
>       'J': ['Jane', 'Judith'],
>       'M': ['Mary', 'Melody', 'Myriam'],
>       'L': ['Lauren'] })

Now to get the counts of each initial letter:

```
counts = {k: len(v) for k, v in name_lists.items()}
```

> {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'H': 1, 'K': 1, 'J': 2, 'M': 3, 'L': 1}

I've changed many variable names since they shadow built-in functions.

Comment: Use ``f`` instead of ``f.readlines()``. File objects are iterables in Python. By doing this you can also cut out ``line.strip()``.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick, just change the name from file.txt to your files name:

```
def newDictionary():
    names={}
    file = open('file.txt')
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    if len(lines) == 1 and len(lines[0]) == 0:
        print('empty file')
    else:
        for line in lines:
            if line[0] in names:
                names[(line[0])].append(line)
            else:
                names[(line[0])] = [line,] 
    return names
```

basically what it does is read the file, split into lines, then iterate over the lines, check if the 1st char of that line is already in the dictionary. If it is not, add it as key, where the value is an array containing the name read. If it is, just append the name to the array corresponding to that key.

Obs: I changed a previous answer that was keeping the new lines on the end of the names.

Comment: Ok I see what you changed but when adding the splitlines() then the code doesn't work. It was working fine before that with the exception that it was printing \n after each name since they are in new lines, I need to get ride of that. I know I have to do it with .split() but this is only for strings not list, so how do I do that?

Comment: @April what problem are you getting with splitlines()? I just tested it and it works fine for me

Comment: @April I changed it to split(), try it now. Although I don't know why you'd have a problem with splitlines

Comment: It says that 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. And there is also an error in the line that says line[0] in names: the error is string index out of range

Comment: @April sorry, i had a typo, files instead of file. Try now

Comment: now this is what it says as an error,     if line[0] in names:
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @April did you change it to `lines = file.read().split('\n')` instead of `lines = files.read().split('\n')` as it was before ?

Comment: @April or are you not trying it with an empty file?? If the file is empty you'll get that error

Comment: @April I added some protection so the program won't crash with an empty file

Comment: yes I made all the changes but it still says that the string index is out of range

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdefault`:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        lst = [(line[0], line.strip())]
        for k,v in lst:
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print (d)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['Anna'], 'B': ['Betty'], 'H': ['Holley'], 'K': ['Kim'], 'J': ['Jane', 'Judith'], 'M': ['Mary', 'Melody', 'Myriam'], 'L': ['Lauren']}
```